# Flutter how to pass messages to the isolate created by Android AlarmManager

Tags: android, flutter, alarmmanager, dart-isolates

I am using Android `AlarmManger` to set a `oneShotAt` alarm at a particular date and time. I am playing a looping sound with the help of `FlutterRingtonePlayer` as soon as the alarm is activated.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();
  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;

  static playLocalAsset() {
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
    print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId}");
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm(looping: true);
  }

  static stopLocalAsset() {
    print("TEST");
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
  }
  void stopMusic() async {
    AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(Duration(seconds: 0), helloAlarmID, stopLocalAsset);
  }
  //Date and Time Picking
  Future<Null> selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    await selectDate(context);
    _time = await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: _time);
    _date = DateTime(_date.year, _date.month, _date.day, _time.hour, _time.minute);
    print(_date);
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShotAt(_date, helloAlarmID, playLocalAsset); //ALARM SET HERE
  }

  Future<Null> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    _date = await showDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: _date, firstDate: _date, lastDate: DateTime(2222));
  }
```

So alarm is set perfectly and it rings on exact time set. However, when I want to stop the music, I am unable to stop it. So I had to use another `oneShot` of `AlarmManager` in order to access the isolate and stop the music as seen in the code above. This stops the music, but it takes more than 3 seconds just to stop the music.

My question is, how do I make the `AlarmManger` stop the music IMMEDIATELY as soon as the stop button is pressed.

Thank You,
Jack

EDIT: Removed a line that was kept for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after searching through the web I finnally found a way to stop the player immediately after you press.

As `AlarmManger` creates an isolate, you must create a recieve port inside `callback` function of the `AlarmManger`.In my case it is `static playLocalAsset()`

```
static playLocalAsset() {
    ReceivePort rcPort = new ReceivePort();
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(rcPort.sendPort, portName);
    rcPort.listen((v) {
      FlutterRingtonePlayer.stop();
    });
    final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
    print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId}");
    FlutterRingtonePlayer.playAlarm(looping: true);
  }
```

create a portname outside all functions (a global variable per say) like

```
const String portName = "ConnectingIsolate";
```

Now in your stop button function create a `SendPort` which will send to the portname that you have declared globally. In my case, the final `stopLocalAsset()` will look like

```
void stopMusic() {
    SendPort sendPort = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(portName);
    sendPort.send("Abcd");
  }
```

So, basically, when you send something through `SendPort`, the receiever port (which is in isolate) will listen and perform whatever operation that you have provided in `rcport.listen` function, which in my case is to stop the player.

Hope this helps.